# For loop adds a JSON response twice instead of once

Tags: android, json

Actually I am parsing a JSON and store ts data in model class. But the data of a particular Array adding two times please help me. I am unable to detect where I am doing my coding wrong.

I have just update my code please check and give me the solution. Problem is that data insde the array(data) was not as expected. It will duplicated to all the objects inside it.

Here are my coding sheets:

This is my model class:

```
ConfigurableProductModel {

public String color_name;
public String color_id;
public ArrayList<Data> data;


public ArrayList<Data> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Data> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public List<String> total_size;

public String getColor_name() {
    return color_name;
}

public void setColor_name(String color_name) {
    this.color_name = color_name;
}

public String getColor_id() {
    return color_id;
}

public void setColor_id(String color_id) {
    this.color_id = color_id;
}


public List<String> getTotal_size() {
    return total_size;
}

public void setTotal_size(List<String> total_size) {
    this.total_size = total_size;
}


public static class Data{


    public String pro_id;

    public String getPro_id() {
        return pro_id;
    }

    public void setPro_id(String pro_id) {
        this.pro_id = pro_id;
    }

    public String getPro_size() {
        return pro_size;
    }

    public void setPro_size(String pro_size) {
        this.pro_size = pro_size;
    }

    public String pro_size;


}
}
```

Here I am parsing the data

```
   try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new 
      JSONArray(response.toString());

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {

                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    ConfigurableProductModel configurableProductModel=new ConfigurableProductModel();

                    configurableProductModel.setColor_name(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    configurableProductModel.setColor_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));




                       JSONArray jsonArray_data=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                       sizes_list.clear();

                       for(int m=0;m<jsonArray_data.length();m++)
                      {

                       JSONObject jsonObject_data=jsonArray_data.getJSONObject(m);

                        ConfigurableProductModel.Data data=new ConfigurableProductModel.Data();
                        data.setPro_id(jsonObject_data.getString("entity_id"));
                        data.setPro_size(jsonObject_data.getString("size_label"));

                         sizes_list.add(jsonObject_data.getString("size_label"));

                         datasmodels.add(data);
                configurableProductModel.setData(data);

                      }


                    configurableProductModel.setTotal_size(sizes_list);
                    configurableProductModels.add(configurableProductModel);

                }
```

After parsing:

```
[{
    "color_id": "20",
    "color_name": "Mountain",
    "data": [{
        "pro_id": "785",
        "pro_size": "169"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "786",
        "pro_size": "179"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "787",
        "pro_size": "189"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "782",
        "pro_size": "169"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "783",
        "pro_size": "179"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "784",
        "pro_size": "189"
    }],
    "total_size": ["169", "179", "189"]
}, {
    "color_id": "30",
    "color_name": "Sky Blue",
    "data": [{
        "pro_id": "785",
        "pro_size": "169"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "786",
        "pro_size": "179"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "787",
        "pro_size": "189"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "782",
        "pro_size": "169"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "783",
        "pro_size": "179"
    }, {
        "pro_id": "784",
        "pro_size": "189"
    }],
    "total_size": ["169", "179", "189"]
}]
```

Comment: What fields are duplicated? Can you show the expected data?

Comment: which are your expected result and output result. jsonArray_data.length() equals 2, so the loop executed twice.

Comment: i am updating my question please check guys]

Comment: [{"color_id":"20","color_name":"Mountain","data":[{"pro_id":"785","pro_size":"169"},{"pro_id":"786","pro_size":"179"},{"pro_id":"787","pro_size":"189"}],"total_size":["169","179","189"]},{"color_id":"30","color_name":"Sky Blue","data":[{"pro_id":"782","pro_size":"169"},{"pro_id":"783","pro_size":"179"},{"pro_id":"784","pro_size":"189"}],"total_size":["169","179","189"]}]

Comment: THis is my expected output

Comment: Where have you created sizes_list?

Comment: actually sizes_list not creating problem for me

Comment: data inside the array (data)  was not expected

Comment: Ok, Where have you created datamodels

Comment: What is in this line? `datasmodels.add(data);` Is datasmodels is a Arraylist?

Comment: jsonObject_data.getString("size_label") does this method works?? I cant find any label with "size_label"??

Answer (score 1):

**My guess to your error i will add this answer.**

In your code

```
datasmodels.add(data);
```

above code seems to be arraylist for data object model.

Then your code should be like this

```
 for(int m=0;m<jsonArray_data.length();m++)
      {
        JSONObject jsonObject_data=jsonArray_data.getJSONObject(m);

        /* Declare your arraylist for data object here..! */
        ArrayList<Data> datasmodels = new ArrayList();

        ConfigurableProductModel.Data data=new ConfigurableProductModel.Data();
        data.setPro_id(jsonObject_data.getString("entity_id"));
        data.setPro_size(jsonObject_data.getString("size_label"));

        sizes_list.add(jsonObject_data.getString("size_label"));

        datasmodels.add(data);
        configurableProductModel.setData(datasmodels); //Changed Here

      }
```

> Your problem is `datamodels` keeps the previuos data so make  it declare inside the for loop will recreate everytime to load new data.